# Place image in front of html video

Tags: html, image, video, z-index

I want to place an image in front of html video. And here is my code so far:

```
    <style>
    video.videos {
        background-image: url(image.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        z-index:1;
    }
    </style>

<video id="Video1" class="videos" >
    <img src="image.png" align="absmiddle" style="z-index:2;" >
    <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source> 
         Browser does not support HTML5. Video could not be loaded.

</video>
```

But using z-index does not make it working. I mean, the image still remains behind the video file. Is there a possibility to fix this? Maybe any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place it outside the video tags and use this style to position it:

```
top: 100px; left: 100px; z-index: 0; position: absolute;
```

Naturally, you'll need to adjust values for your specific application. If absolute positioning doesn't work for you, you can always use relative positioning, which can be more flexible. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75B7G/) for an example of  positioning an image in front of a video.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This works, but the problem is, I have my video file moving from one div to another (on button click). So, the video moves to other place, but the image stays at the same place. Any possibility to "attach" it somehow?

Comment: How exactly are you moving it? If you're using `document.getElementById("someID").innerHTML = someHTML` (or something of that sort) you could include the the HTML for the image. For example, if you have two DIVs with IDs "div1" and div2" (the video _and_ image must be in the div1), you could move it with `document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML; document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "";` You'd also need to use relative positioning (instead of absolute). The above just copies the HTML, but you could completely re-generate it.

Comment: @StartedFromTheBottom I finally got around and made a complete eample of moving the image and video. See http://jsfiddle.net/75B7G/1/.

Comment: Hey @Nateowami , thanks for the answer. Works as it should be, but I am making something more complex, so this will not be good solution for me. I will have to keep looking for an other way. But this answers my question anyway!

Answer (score 1):

What you mean with front of html video?
if it's the image poster, you can use this:

```html
<video width="320" height="240" poster="/images/w3html5.gif" controls>
   <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```